# LINQ to SQL expression to embed into main query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

Making a forum application. I have topics and messages (replies). I want messages being pulled from database to attach "is liked by current user" flag and some other information related to the message.
With LINQ I can get it like this:

```
var messages = _repoMessages.GetAll()
               .Select(m => new { Message = m, 
                                  IsLikedByCurrentUser = m.Likes
                                    .Any(l => l.UserId == currentUserId)});
```

where *currentUserId* is provided from some code above.

I have three or more different queries that need this flag populated and need this logic to be repeated for every of them. Is there a way to have a single piece of code (expression? func?) that calcs the flag so it can be used in LINQ expressions and **well translated to SQL**? Obviously, if i make Func that does the goal then I'll not be able to embed it into code above as Func cannot be translated to sql query.

**UPDATE**

Possible workarounds:

1. Create a db view that joins messages and usrs "likes" and then make
   it as a virtual navigation prop in the Message EF entity
2. Use proxy Select(new { Message = m, CurrentUserId = currentUserId})
   that injects user Id and then apply stand-alone expression that
   translates this into what I need

but woild like more nice solution :)

Comment: You can prepare own function that build `ExpressionTree` - then it will be recoognized by EF.

Comment: @pwas yes i thought of that but still not dont have deep knowledges  of how to make own trees...

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka Then it sounds like it's time for you to learn.

Comment: *Is there a way to have a single piece of code (expression? func?) that calcs the flag so it can be used in LINQ expressions and well translated to SQL?*

Yes, it is. It's called <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx">groupping</a>:

**SQL:**

    SELECT Flag, Count(*)
    FROM Messages
    WHERE UserId = @CurrentUserId
    GROUP BY Flag